# Odoo 9: Fixed header with vertical and horizontal scroll in list view and order view odoo 9

Tags: listview, odoo, odoo-9, fixed-header-tables

How can I make header fix in a list view and order lines with vertical and horizontal scroll bar in Odoo9.

I have used web_list_view_sticky module and modified as below.

```
openerp.web_list_view_sticky = function (instance) {
var _t = instance.web._t,
    _lt = instance.web._lt;
var QWeb = instance.web.qweb;

//Sticky Table Header
instance.web.ListView.include({
    load_list: function () {
        var self = this;

        self._super.apply(this, arguments);

        var scrollArea = $('.oe_list')[0];

            self.$el.find('table.oe_list_content').each(function(){
                $(this).stickyTableHeaders({scrollableArea: scrollArea})
            });

    },
});
```

};

Comment: @CZoellner I have added some details. I would greatly appreciate if you provide me some help.

Answer (score 0):

For Odoo v9 use like this:

```
$(this).stickyTableHeaders({scrollableArea: scrollArea, leftOffset:scrollArea, **"fixedOffset": 1** })
```

and used lib/sticky_table_header.js updated 
version(https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders/blob/master/js/jquery.stickytableheaders.js)
This works after load.